# Doctrine include null on join

Tags: sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a query that will fetch every users, and, for those that have received a feedback, fetch their rating average as well.

After some research, I have crafted a query that will return all the users that have received a feedback and their respective rating. Which is a start. However I don't get the users with no feedback when I add the `->leftJoin('AppFeedbackBundle:Feedback', 'f', 'WITH', 'u.id = f.user')`

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select(array( 'u', 'AVG(r.ratings)' ))
            ->orderBy('u.lastLogin', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->leftJoin('AppFeedbackBundle:Feedback', 'f', 'WITH', 'u.id = f.user')
            ->join('f.rating', 'r')
            ->groupBy('u.id');
```

Do you know how I could get both the users with and without feedbacks, and associate said feedback to those who have one?

#### Remark

I would like to avoid reversing the ManyToOne relationship (feedback <-> user) in the User entity because I tend to fetch users all the time and I feel that I will end up having lots of feedbacks, hence I don't want to have those every time I get users, for performance reasons (please tell me if you don't think this performance argument is relevant or you think it does not matter much).

#### Note

The links between feedbacks, users and ratings are all in the feedback entity, like such:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\FeedbackBundle\Entity\Rating", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $rating;
```

Comment: left join rating too? not sure if all users have rating or only ones who have feedback

Comment: Oh you are correct. That is unclear. All the users who have feedback do have a rating! :)

Comment: good i added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left Join Rating too as all users who have feedback have rating but not the ones without feedback.

Comment: I could not do proper testing earlier. Looks like you are very correct. Thank you!